# javascript canvas points rotation

Tags: javascript, matrix, html5-canvas

Trying to implement rotation matrix in javascript. 3d but can't get 2d right. (I can plug and play three.js I want to get my hands on the underlying math just because)

I set up a points matrix and center on display. The points rotate but their distance between them gets smaller as if they are receding. Instead of points it's a two pixel line. Here is the matrix

```
let sin = Math.sin;
let cos = Math.cos;
let ang = (Math.PI / 180) * 10;
for(let p=0; p < PTS.Demo.pts.length; p++) {
    PTS.Demo.pts[p][0] = Math.round((PTS.Demo.pts[p][0] * cos(ang)) - (PTS.Demo.pts[p][1] * sin(ang)));
    PTS.Demo.pts[p][1] = Math.round((PTS.Demo.pts[p][0] * sin(ang)) + (PTS.Demo.pts[p][1] * cos(ang)));
}
```

With Math.round the points "recede" for a few rotations and then settle down(?). Without rounding they "shrink" to a point. Hoping it's something stupid and easy to spot. Thanks for any ideas. Full code pasted bellow.

--------code-----------

```
'use strict'

window.PTS = window.PTS || {}
PTS.Demo = PTS.Demo || {};

PTS.Demo.pts = [
    [-20,20],
    [20,20],
    [20,-20],
    [-20,-20]
];

PTS.Demo.trySimple = function() {
    document.addEventListener('keydown', function(ev) {
        switch (ev.keyCode) {
            case 37 ://left
                PTS.Demo.rotateMe();
            break;
        }
    });
    PTS.Demo.canvas = document.getElementById('cnv');
    PTS.Demo.canvas.width = PTS.Demo.canvas.offsetWidth;
    PTS.Demo.canvas.height = PTS.Demo.canvas.offsetHeight;
    PTS.Demo.centx = PTS.Demo.canvas.width / 2;
    PTS.Demo.centy = PTS.Demo.canvas.height / 2;
    PTS.Demo.ctx = PTS.Demo.canvas.getContext('2d');
    PTS.Demo.drawPts();
}
PTS.Demo.rotateMe = function() {
    let sin = Math.sin;
    let cos = Math.cos;
    let ang = (Math.PI / 180) * 10;
    for(let p=0; p < PTS.Demo.pts.length; p++) {
        PTS.Demo.pts[p][0] = Math.round((PTS.Demo.pts[p][0] * cos(ang)) - (PTS.Demo.pts[p][1] * sin(ang)));
        PTS.Demo.pts[p][1] = Math.round((PTS.Demo.pts[p][0] * sin(ang)) + (PTS.Demo.pts[p][1] * cos(ang)));
    }
    PTS.Demo.drawPts();
}
PTS.Demo.drawPts = function() {
    PTS.Demo.ctx.clearRect (0, 0,PTS.Demo.canvas.width, PTS.Demo.canvas.height);
    for(let p=0; p < PTS.Demo.pts.length; p++) {
        let px = PTS.Demo.centx + PTS.Demo.pts[p][0];
        let py = PTS.Demo.centy + PTS.Demo.pts[p][1];
        let xp = px + 2;
        let yp = py + 2;
        PTS.Demo.ctx.beginPath();
        PTS.Demo.ctx.moveTo(px, py);
        PTS.Demo.ctx.lineTo(xp, yp);
        PTS.Demo.ctx.closePath();
        PTS.Demo.ctx.stroke();
        PTS.Demo.ctx.fill();
    }
}
```